# How can I filter an array on matching array keys from another array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here are my arrays:

```
$not_wanted = array('example1', 'example2');

$from_this_array= array(

'example1'=>'value1',
'example2'=>'value2',
'should_stay'=>'value3'

)
```

at the end I should have

```
array('should_stay'=>'value3')
```

what I have been trying but it has a sickness

```
public function aaData($array){
    $aaData =array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$item){        
        if(array_key_exists($key, $this->unset_array)){
            unset($array[$key]);
            $aaData[] = $item;
        }
    }
    var_dump($aaData);
    return $aaData;
}
```

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$not_wanted = array('example1', 'example2');
$from_this_array= array(
  'example1'=>'value1',
  'example2'=>'value2',
  'should_stay'=>'value3'
);

print_r(array_diff_key(
  $from_this_array, array_flip($not_wanted)));
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/jPLJsufA).

Note that [**array_diff**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) is not relevant here, as it checks values, not keys. As your first (`$not_wanted`) array contains values, it should be flipped (turned into a hash) to use [**array_diff_key**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, here is the working version of your code:

```
function aaData($array){
    $aaData =array();
    foreach ($array as $key=>$item){        
        if(!in_array($key, $this->unset_array)){
            $aaData[$key] = $item;
        }
    }
    var_dump($aaData);
    return $aaData;
}
```

You used `array_key_exists` on the array that stores the keys that should be excluded - but in this array, they are the values, not the keys, so you need `in_array()` instead. Also it did not make sense to do `unset()` on the original array, as you will only return the modified one.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/vz4bcs6p)

Comment: Yes I know was a bad approach what I was doing thanks to you as well!!

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
foreach ($from_this_array as $key => $val) {
   if (in_array($key, $not_wanted)) {
      unset($from_this_array[$key]);
   }
}
```

See [**working demo**](http://codepad.org/T2BlX2cb)

Answer (score 0):

```
function aaData($array, $not_wanted){
  foreach ($not_wanted as $key){        

    if(isset($array[$key])){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
return $array;
}

$not_wanted = array('example1', 'example2');

$array= array(

'example1'=>'value1',
'example2'=>'value2',
'should_stay'=>'value3'

);

print_r(aaData($array, $not_wanted));
```